# select TableData where ColumnData start with list of strings

Tags: sql, sql-like, startswith

Following is the query to select column data from table, where column data starts with a OR b OR c. But the answer i am looking for is to Select data which starts with List of Strings.

```
SELECT *  FROM Table WHERE Name LIKE '[abc]%'
```

But i want something like

```
SELECT *  FROM Table WHERE Name LIKE '[ab,ac,ad,ae]%'
```

Can anybody suggest what is the best way of selecting column data which starts with list of String, I don't want to use OR operator, List of strings specifically.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

The most general solution you would have to use is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Name LIKE 'ab%' OR Name LIKE 'ac%' OR Name LIKE 'ad%' OR Name LIKE 'ae%';
```

However, certain databases offer some regex support which you might be able to use.  For example, in SQL Server you could write:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE NAME LIKE 'a[bcde]%';
```

MySQL has a `REGEXP` operator which supports regex `LIKE` operations, and you could write:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE NAME REGEXP '^a[bcde]';
```

Oracle and Postgres also have regex like support.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but with the following part i meant the string could be anything. LIKE '[ab,ac,ad,ae]%' could also be something LIKE '[ab,cd,asdd,abc]%'. I wanted to use kind of list of strings if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52235468/2422776), another approach could be to join your table with a sub-query of those values:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable t
JOIN   (SELECT 'ab' AS value
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ac'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ad'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ae') v ON t.vame LIKE v.value || '%'
```